# Remove header from Container

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the header out of the container so that I can make the header to stretch the full width of the screen (i've been messing with it for hours without luck before realizing the container was preventing it). Here's the HTML:

```
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="wrapper">  

<div id="header">

    <div class="container clearfix">

        <div id="logo">         
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="logo_img">
                <img src="<?php echo $of_option['st_logo_image'] ?>" alt>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'custom_menu')); ?> 

            <?php if($of_option['st_responsive']) responsive_select_nav() ?>
        </div>        

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn how to properly structure an HTML layout. I separated the header and put it before the container so they are independent.

```css
#header {background: #eee; height: 50px;}
.container {background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin: auto; height: 200px;}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header here</div>

<div class="container clearfix">

  <div id="logo">
    <a href="" class="logo_img">
      <img src="" alt="Logo here">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navigation">
    PHP stuff here
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: To be fair, I didn't write the code. It was built into the theme that way. I made your changes but it still isn't working. It's still only as wide as the container.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you further without seeing it live. It works for the code from your question but there's obviously something else in the live version.

Comment: The address is sheisbiddy.com I'll turn off construction mode for you!

Comment: Oh, I see, it's because your #wrapper is 980px and the header is inside it. Can you put the header outside, above it?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do... sorry if I didn't make that clear!

Comment: Yeah, just go ahead and move the header outside the wrapper.

Comment: Move the element outside the wrapper, not sure how else to tell you: http://jsfiddle.net/tvtp8gte/

Comment: Wow. I feel dumb. Thank you!!

Comment: Don't feel like that - I should've been more clear. You're welcome!